# Is there any oneliner for a kind of explode and concat in PHP

Tags: php

I got string like `1_2_3_4_5` and I want an array like this:

```
array(
 [0] = 1
 [1] = 1_2
 [2] = 1_2_3
 [3] = 1_2_3_4
 [4] = 1_2_3_4_5
)
```

Any idea for a oneliner?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Is there a reason that the key `1` is missing?

Comment: no :-) just a mistake and corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$input = '1_2_3_4_5';

// Get an array with 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5
$parts = explode('_', $input);

$output = [];

$i = 1;

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    // array_slice() will take 1 to n elements from the array of numbers
    $values = array_slice($parts, 0, $i++);
    // Join the values
    $output[] = implode('_', $values);
}

print_r($output);
```

It will show this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1_2
    [2] => 1_2_3
    [3] => 1_2_3_4
    [4] => 1_2_3_4_5
)
```

[Try it at 3V4L](https://3v4l.org/lUWD2).

Comment: thx for your time. At least it is no problem to get my result, but mostly I create 10 lines of code because I dont know the simple way in one line ;-)

Comment: @do1emu You can put all this code on one line if you want, but it will be unreadable. I don't see the point in making it an oneliner, do you have constraints on the size of your code?

Comment: at leas thx the array_slice help a lot to to it in 2 lines - thats ok ;-)

Answer (score 1):

just for fun using substr

```
$st = '1_2_3_4_5';


$num[]=$st;

while($pos=strrpos($st,'_')){
  $num[]=$st=substr($st,0,$pos);
}sort($num);


print_r($num);


Output
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1_2
    [2] => 1_2_3
    [3] => 1_2_3_4
    [4] => 1_2_3_4_5
)
```